# How to solve the limit of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to solve this limit?

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n(2^n+1)}\bigg)^{1,3n} $$

I tried using the definition of e as a limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+{x_n})^{y_n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n}$$

but to no success.

Comment: Write it as $\left[\left(1+\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+2^n}\right)^{\frac{4^n+2^n}{3^n-2^n}}\right]^{\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+2^n}\cdot 1,3n}$. Note how the part inside the $[\cdot]$ tends to $e$. Then, to determine the limit of the exponent $\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+2^n}\cdot 1,3n$ divide numerator and denominator by $4^n$.

Comment: What does $\left(\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n(2^n+1)}\right)^{1,3n}$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left (\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n+4^n} \right)^{1.3n}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{4^n(1+(3/4)^n}{4^n(1+(1/2)^n}\right)^{1.3n}=1.$$
When $n$ is large $4^n$ dominates in both Num an Den.

**In OP's way:**

$$L=  \exp[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1.3n \left (\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n+4^n}-1 \right)=\exp\left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1.3n \left (\frac{3^n-2^n}{2^n+4^n}\right)\right]=\exp\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  1.3n ~(3/4)^n$$ $$\implies L= \exp \left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1.3 \frac{n}{(4/3)^{n}}\right]=1.$$ The last limit is by L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: its not $1/(3n)$ but rather $1,3n$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hôpital's rule

=(n(3/2)^n-1+n(4/2)^n-1)/(n2^n-1))

=((3/2)^n-1+(4/2)^n-1)/(2^n-1))

=(3^n-1+4^n-1)/(2^n-1*2^n-1)

=(3/4)^n-1+1

=1[image]